# How to display one image in multiple sizes across the site?

Tags: media

I would like one image to show in different locations, for example:

- Event in the Calendar (Cropped version of the image)
- Homepage (if promoted to Front Page - as the full size of the image)

Is this possible using Drupal 7?

Thanks!
Izumi.

Comment: https://drupal.org/project/imagecache. imagecache module will help you

Comment: Thank you @HituBansal I will evaluate the following in the next few days - thanks for your suggestion. https://drupal.org/project/imagecache
https://drupal.org/project/imagecrop
https://drupal.org/project/imagefield_crop
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_url/7
https://drupal.org/project/formatter_field
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/96979/how-to-display-one-image-in-multiple-sizes-across-the-site

Answer (score 1):

Imagecache module has been moved into core for Drupal 7

It's called [Image Styles](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/image)

I haven't used the module, but [Image Formatter Link To Image Styles](https://drupal.org/project/image_formatter_link_to_image_style) module exposes the Image Style presets in in the imagefield

Answer (score 0):

To speed up page loads (especially if you use Image magic and need many different sizes on images that users will load) I try to create only one image style, whenever I can, of the largest size I will use. Then, when I need the same image in a smaller size I call on this same image style and shrink it either with HTML or CSS (e.g.: height:20px; width: 20px;) Of course, it's better if you keep the image withe same height/width ratio.)

If you can imagine hundreds or thousands of users uploading images that need to be cropped, scaled, etc. that can take some resources on the server. The method above minimizes that. :)